# About saving View objects in firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Im currently working on drawing app and I need to save draw of one of the player in the database
I undrestood that I supposed to use `setValue` method to save data on specific child:

```
rooms.child("room " + player.roomNumber).child("draw").setValue(paintView);
```

"paintView" is my View object.

When running I get this error message:

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isFocusable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is suggesting that you can't use an Android View object as a value in Realtime Database.  You can only store data types that are compatible with JSON: string, number, boolean, array, object.

If you're trying to save image data, it's probably not a good idea to use a database at all.  Consider instead uploading image data to Cloud Storage instead. You will need to write code to extract the image data from any views you're working with.

Comment: How can I get url of the image with DataSnapshot created ?